# SQL Server BPA output result confusing

Tags: sql, sql-server

I installed SQL Server BPA in our SQL Server 2008 R2 box and run the analyzer.  The result from the analyzer is very confusing that it tells me the password policy for SQL logins is turned off.  I looked in all the logins and the password policy is turned on.  Is there a bug in BPA?  Please help

Answer (score 0):

You can find the policy of each SQL login with this query:

```
SELECT name, is_policy_checked
FROM master.sys.sql_logins
```

Comment: Thank you Dave, I run the query here and for all sql logins the value is 1 i.e. is enabled. However, the BPA is telling me it is not enabled.  Is there anything I missing reading the BPA?